# Insert records from one table on another table incrementing id

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I insert records from one table(table1) to the same table(table2) in a different SQL database?

However the destination table already exists and had records with the same id(c1). the records of the table1 must be added to table2, but I have to increment the field (c1).

table 1

```
C1;C2;C3;
1;Name 1;Address 1;
2;Name 2;Address 2;
3;Name 3;Address 3;
4;Name 4;Address 4;
```

table 2

```
C1;C2;C3 ;
1;Name 11;Address 11;
2;Name 12;Address 12;
3;Name 13;Address 13;
4;Name 14;Address 14;
5;Name 1;Address 1;
6;Name 2;Address 2;
7;Name 3;Address 3;
8;Name 4;Address 4;
```

**what is wrong?**
table cl is the same in both databases and as the following columns:
(clstamp, nome, no, estab, vendnm, ncont)

```
INSERT INTO DB2..cl(clstamp, nome, estab, vendnm, ncont)
    select clstamp, nome, estab, vendnm, ncont
      FROM         [DB1]..[cl]
      LEFT JOIN    [DB2]..[cl] ON [DB1]..[cl].clstamp=[DB2]..[cl].clstamp 
      and [DB1]..[cl].nome=[DB2]..[cl].nome 
      and [DB1]..[cl].estab=[DB2]..[cl].estab 
      and [DB1]..[cl].vendm=[DB2]..[cl].vendnm 
      and [DB1]..[cl].ncont=[DB2]..[cl].ncont
    where [DB1]..cl.ncont not in (select ncont from [DB2]..cl) 
    order by [DB2]..[cl].no
```

Comment: Try the Export Wizard. Right click a database > Tasks > Export Data

Comment: Does table2 have an identity column for C1? Also, are they on the same server?

Comment: yes, c1 is an identity column and they are in the same server

Comment: If you want to keep a reference in table2 to the original records in table1, then you could add an extra field in table2. F.e. named "table1ID".  But then again, that would go against the spirit of [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

Comment: no, I do not need a reference to table1. I only need to scan the last number in column c1 and increment +1 to that column.

Answer (score 1):

If your databases are on the same server, and table 2 has column C1 marked as an identity column, then you can generally execute a straightforward SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO database2..table2(C2, C3)
SELECT C2, C3
FROM database1..table1
ORDER BY C1 ASC
```

Comment: This will not work. Identities can and will have gaps. They jump by 10,000 or so when the server is restarted. And any rows that are deleted also generate gaps. Unless of course they don't care if they can tie the rows together anymore. If that is the case then this works just fine.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. the column c1 is not identity, is the primary key only. Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_cl'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid inserting duplicate rows, please try this:

```
INSERT INTO database2..myTable2 (C2, C3)
        select t1.c2, t1.c3
          FROM         [database1]..[table1] t1
          LEFT JOIN    [database2]..[table2] t2 ON t1.C2 = t2.C2 and t1.C3 = t2.C3
        where t2.c2 is null and t2.c3 is null
        order by t1.C1
```

If you are okay with duplicates then the solution is already mentioned by Angelo.

I tried with temp tables and working code is below:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable1') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #myTable1
END;

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable2') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #myTable2
END;

CREATE TABLE #myTable1 ([C1] int identity(1,1), [C2]  varchar(10),  [C3]  varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE #myTable2 ([C1] int identity(1,1), [C2]  varchar(10),  [C3]  varchar(10));

Insert INTO #myTable1(C2, C3)
values
 ('Name 1', 'Address 1')
, ('Name 2', 'Address 2')
, ('Name 3', 'Address 3')
, ('Name 4', 'Address 4')

Insert INTO #myTable2(C2, C3)
values
  ('Name 11', 'Address 11')
, ('Name 12', 'Address 12')
, ('Name 13', 'Address 13')
, ('Name 14', 'Address 14')

select * from #myTable1
select * from #myTable2

INSERT INTO #myTable2 (C2, C3)
    select t1.c2, t1.c3
      FROM         [#myTable1] t1
      LEFT JOIN    [#myTable2] t2 ON t1.C2 = t2.C2 and t1.C3 = t2.C3
    where t2.c2 is null and t2.c3 is null
    order by t1.C1

select * from #myTable2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't manually add any settings like `IDENTITY_INSERT`, all the records inserted would naturally be granted with incremental IDs.

As you described, the problem you have here is the ***duplicate records*** that violates your  *PRIMARY KEY constraint*.

The most straightforward way is using a `MERGE` statement.
`MERGE INTO` Table 2 `USING` Table 1.
`WHEN MATCHED` do nothing and insert the records when `UNMATCHED`

Also, be aware that if you `DELETE` any records, the deleted ID won't be recycled for the newly inserted rows. Thus check the table if you want the original IDs and the inserted IDs flow continuously

Comment: How can I do the merge statement? only adding, not updating or delete.